# c# deserializing text with guids to json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I get the following json from a service contract (solr)

```
{"highlighting":{
   "394c65f1-dfb1-4b76-9b6c-2f14c9682cc9":{
      "PackageName":["- <em>Testing<em> channel twenty."]},
   "baf8434a-99a4-4046-8a4d-2f7ec09eafc8":{
      "PackageName":["- <em>Testing<em> channel twenty."]},
   "0a699062-cd09-4b2e-a817-330193a352c1":{
     "PackageName":["- <em>Testing<em> channel twenty."]},
   "0b9ec891-5ef8-4085-9de2-38bfa9ea327e":{
     "PackageName":["- <em>Testing<em> channel twenty."]}}
}
```

when using http://json2csharp.com/ i can't deserialize it because the guids are in the attribute names field.
Is there a way I can deserialize this to c# object (I can call name the guid another name i.e. Id)?
thanks.

Comment: if you control the input format you can move guids inside object, like `{"Id": "GUID", "PackageName":["- <em>Testing<em> channel twenty."]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deserialize this JSON string as `Dictionary<Guid, Package>`:

**Example:**

```
string json = @"{
""326EAFDC-3553-4AA6-9D3B-79CC666A264C"": {...},
""70C57804-A9AF-41FC-9867-42C621E5A465"": {...}    
}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<Guid, Package>>(json);
```